# Yii's CArrayDataProvider and new rows

Tags: yii, grid, master-detail, cactivedataprovider

Is there a way to show in a Grid that takes it data from CActiveDataProvider some new rows that are not actually yet into the database?

here's my scenario..

I have to fill by X times (the quantity of a product in a bill) and provide to each row the possibility to be edited and saved

```
 Product    QTY 
 product1   3
     |
     ____  Edit item 1 (not yet in the db)
     ____  Edit item 2 (not yet in the db)
     ____  Edit item 3 (not yet in the db)
```

So it's kind of like a master detail grid (That I've sorted it out how to do it..)
but I can't display things on a grid that arren't yet in the database..

I know I have to create an array of temporary models like $model[]=new MODEL(); and push the somehow to the CActiveDataProvider but don't know the syntaxis...

Comment: Did you try it with `CActiveDataProvider`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with `CActiveDataProvider` because as the documentation says

> CActiveDataProvider provides data in terms of ActiveRecord objects which are of class modelClass. It uses the AR CActiveRecord::findAll method to retrieve the data from database.

However, there is [CArrayDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider). You can put arbitrary data in it, ie. merge an array of real objects with an array of empty ones and use that.

```
$rawData=array(
    array('id'=>1, 'username'=>'from', 'email'=>'array'),
    array('id'=>2, 'username'=>'test 2', 'email'=>'hello@example.com'),
  );

$arrayDataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($rawData, array(
    'id'=>'id',
    'sort'=>array(
        'attributes'=>array(
            'username', 'email',
        ),
    ),
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>10,
    ),
));
```

As you can see, the data here is a simple array, but you can even sort the data.